# Could a high energy content prevent a singularity inside a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

Very roughly, dark energy tends to cause space to expand and mass tends to cause space to contract. If nothing gets in the way, the math on that contraction breaks down when it forms a black hole singularity.

So the question is, can enough energy halt the contraction before it forms a singularity, but after it forms a black hole (i.e. an event horizon)? Are there any theories that have tried to use this to avoid the the math breaking down?

---

Edit: after some digging, I have found that the [Penrose-Hawking singularity theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose%E2%80%93Hawking_singularity_theorems) gives conditions where a singularity *must* form, but I've yet to find a description of what happens (or could happen) if those conditions are not met. Namely, it seems like "interesting" thing might happen if negative energy became part of the conditions inside a black hole.

Comment: When you say "can enough energy halt the contraction" are you referring to dark energy only?

Comment: @Wookie dark energy would be included in what I'm asking about, but I'd not limit the question to that.

Comment: @BCS normal positive energy density will form a singularity, mass is just one type of energy density. Search for "Kugelblitz" to have an idea of what a "pure energy" BH is

Comment: @LolloBoldo okay, so that's the uninteresting case. What about the other cases? (E.g. negative energy density, or "abnormal" positive energy density if that's even a thing.) Are any of them interesting?

Comment: For negative energy density i have to think about it, while "abnormal" positive energy density doesn't mean anything in physics. There is only positive energy density and negative energy density

Comment: Whai i think is that you can put the cosmological term of Einstein-Hilbert action into a energy-momentum tensor and sum it to the usual one. If the sum turns out greater than zero you have the usual singularity BH, if the sum is less than zero you have the standard FLWR metric so no BH at all

Comment: @LolloBoldo IIRC the cosmological term is a constant (the same everywhere). Is that nesseaaraly the only way to get negative energy at some point? Is there anything fundamentally preventing an energy density that gets more negative the further into the BH you go? (And, yes, I know this is quickly getting close to speculative fiction territory.)

Comment: As far as i know the cosmological constant is the only way to have negative energy. You get in the casimir effect a negative pressure but if that gravitates it's still up to debate (check Archimedes Virgo's experiment). For the last question i don't get what you mean

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.03590 The authors calculated that Black Holes and Planck Stars of equal mass possess the same radius for freefalling observers.

Comment: @Wookie very interesting! That goes one step further than I was asking about and proposes an actual mechanism for the energy needed to prevent the similarity. -- OTOH it seems to be a quantum gravity theory, and part of what got me asking this question is wondering if a BH could be fully described with just GR and avoiding a need to invoke quantum gravity.

Answer (score 1):

> what got me asking this question is wondering if a BH could be fully described with just GR and avoiding a need to invoke quantum gravity

General Relativity is the theory that leads us to the notion of a singularity at the core of a Black Hole but that's because it's there that we meet the limit of the theory. So, a Black Hole is fully described with a singularity in GR.

Matter existing without physical structure (in one dimension) and especially a large amount of it, as would be in the case of stellar collapse, is not something with a parallel in the observable universe. Under conditions of extreme energy density, we can produce quark matter but it becomes hadronized immediately because it's strongly interacting. These types of interactions are not possible between matter in a Black Hole because the energy cannot propagate outwards. Energy transfers are bound by *c* and as mentioned in the question (Penrose) trapped light-like surfaces mean that there are no outward paths for any particle or interaction.

So, the only way to avoid a singularity is by "invoking" a quantum theory of gravity, one which might allow gravity to weaken at extremely short distances, for example.

> it seems like "interesting" thing might happen if negative energy became part of the conditions inside a black hole

Hawking Radiation allows for negative energy to be part of the conditions of Black Holes in that energy can be drawn away from it by interactions at the horizon. Through this process, Black Holes continually lose energy and evaporate. So, any mechanism for singularity-prevention based on "energy content" would eventually be unstable, especially as Hawking Radiation is inversely proportional to mass.